# ngChange working on array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm struggling with `angularJS` to make a select with option using `ngRepeat`.
I chose this way because the data that I receive is this:

```
{ 
"id": "day-pro", 
"data": [ 
        { "countries": [ "FRANCE", "SPAIN","GERMANY"] }, 
        { "country": "FRANCE", 
         "achieved": [ 4, 12, 23, 24, 24, 27, 35, 41 ], 
         "target": [ 56, 72, 79, 89, 92, 99, 100, 100 ] 
         } ]}
```

and the directive template I use is this:

```
<div ng-controller="hBarController">
    <select id="sel-day-pro" class="frm-drop" data-ng-change="selectCountry($event)">
        <option data-ng-repeat="opt in Countries">{{opt}}</option>
    </select>
<div class="daily-progress-chart">Select a country</div>
```

In the `daily-progress-chart` div it will be a chart drawn at selection.

The error I have is that the directive requires ngModel but inserting it into require: "^ngModel" won't solve it.

Angular directive here:

```
App.directive('myFrmContent', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        require: '^ngModel',
        template: "<div ng-include=\"getTemplateUrl()\"></div>",
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.getTemplateUrl = function () {
                var btnID = '';
                if ($scope && $scope.widget && $scope.widget.id) {
                    btnID = $scope.widget.id;
                }
                return "htmlTemplates/" + btnID + ".html" || '';
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I don't see why this directive needs `ngModel`. Waht error do you get?

Comment: directive is named 'myFrmContent' but 'my-frm-content' is not in the html?

Comment: Where do you use the directive? There isn't any `<my-frm-content>` element in the HTML. This should be close because really unclear.

Comment: Your json is actually kind of weird in my opinion, do you have hands on it ? Using an array with object that are not consistent is not a good practice. You should instead return an object with keys "countries","country".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually missunderstood the error :

The directive that require the `ng-model` is `ng-change`.

Note : Using `ng-model` (`ng-model="selectedCountry"` for exemple) on a select will automatically update the var (`selectedCountry`) to the actual `value` (or `ng-value`) of the option.

`ng-change` is a directive that trigger some an action on a `ng-model` variable change. This is why it require the `ng-model` directive

You should probably end up with something like this :

```
<div ng-controller="hBarController">
    <select id="sel-day-pro" ng-model="selectedCountry" class="frm-drop" data-ng-change="handleChangeSelectedCountry()">
        <option ng-value="opt" data-ng-repeat="opt in Countries">{{opt}}</option>
    </select>
<div class="daily-progress-chart">Select a country</div>
```

And in your controller :

```
$scope.handleChangeSelectedCountry = function(){
   //Do something you want to do on each change of the selectedCountry value
   //Do NOT manually set the value of selectedCountry
}
```

Hope it helped.

EDIT : Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fmhs6Dj8ozq1v1oTJGHG?p=preview) and a cleaner solution

I came up with this :

```
<select data-ng-model="selectedCountry" 
        data-ng-options="country for country in data.data[0].countries"
        id="sel-day-pro" class="frm-drop">
</select>
<div>Currently selected {{selectedCountry}}</div>
```

With no JS in the controller.

If you need to handle something else than setting the var (`selectedCountry`) follow my advice upper in the answer and use the `ng-change` to handle your needed behavior.

PS : Note that your actual JSON is forcing me to do this `data.data[0].countries` instead of this `data.data.countries`